# How to copy specific range cells from multiple sheets to one sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a master workbook in one folder and 100+ child workbooks in a different folder.

Every week I need to copy a specific range of cells from the child workbooks (sheet name is same for all child books) to master workbook (specific sheet).

I tried a few samples but didn't work out.

Comment: Yes I'm sure someone can help you with your VBA code. Post your efforts to date and we can take a look.

Comment: I have multiple VBA Codes like copy cells data in one method, looping files in one method, moving to last row of master sheet in one method etc.,  I was confused with many examples in internet hence I have asked this question in this forum.  If someone can help me with one VBA Code to do this functionality.

Comment: Then please show *what exactly* you have tried and tell where you get stuck or errors. We need a precise point of where to help you. Otherwise the question is too broad to answer as we are no free code writing service.

Comment: Unfortunately nobody is just going to give you an out of the box solution. Post your current code with specific notes on any errors / problems etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fully agree with guys who told you that none will write the code for you, but you are lucky that I have that already written and there may be other people looking for same info, so here it is.
Put the code to module in your master workbook and replace some data as commented:

```
Option Explicit

Sub GoThroughFilesAndCopyData()

Dim BrowseFolder As String
Dim FileItem As Object
Dim oFolder As Object
Dim FSO As Object
Dim shtWork As Worksheet
Dim lngRow As Long
Dim i As Long: i = 1
Dim strPath As String
Dim MasterSheet As Worksheet
Dim ChildSheet As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ' selecting the folder to look files in
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Title = "Select the folder with child workbooks"
        .Show
        On Error Resume Next
        Err.Clear
        BrowseFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            MsgBox "You didn't select anything!"
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            Exit Sub
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") ' creating filesystem object
    Set oFolder = FSO.getfolder(BrowseFolder) ' creating folder object

    Set MasterSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("masterworksheet_name") 'replace masterworksheet_name with the name of your worksheet in master workbook

    For Each FileItem In oFolder.Files 'looking through each file

        If UCase(FileItem.Name) Like "*.XLS*" Then 'try open only excel files

            i = MasterSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row + 1 ' find last not empty row and get a next one which is empty
            Workbooks.Open (BrowseFolder & Application.PathSeparator & FileItem.Name)
            Set ChildSheet = Workbooks(FileItem.Name).Sheets("worksheet_name") 'worksheet_name - replace with child sheet name

            With ChildSheet ' replace your_range_to_copy with the range on a child sheet you want to copy
                Range("your_range_to_copy").Copy Destination:=MasterSheet.Cells(i, column_number) 'i - is the number of last empty row, replace column_number - must be the column number of range to insert
                .Parent.Close SaveChanges:=False 'close child workbook without saving
            End With

        End If
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want.

Copy a range of each sheet

Note: This example use the function LastRow

```
This example copy the range A1:G1 from each worksheet.
```

Change the range in this code line

```
'Fill in the range that you want to copy
'Set CopyRng = sh.Range("A1:G1")

Sub CopyRangeFromMultiWorksheets()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim DestSh As Worksheet
    Dim Last As Long
    Dim CopyRng As Range

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    'Delete the sheet "RDBMergeSheet" if it exist
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RDBMergeSheet").Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    'Add a worksheet with the name "RDBMergeSheet"
    Set DestSh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    DestSh.Name = "RDBMergeSheet"

    'loop through all worksheets and copy the data to the DestSh
    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If sh.Name <> DestSh.Name Then

            'Find the last row with data on the DestSh
            Last = LastRow(DestSh)

            'Fill in the range that you want to copy
            Set CopyRng = sh.Range("A1:G1")

            'Test if there enough rows in the DestSh to copy all the data
            If Last + CopyRng.Rows.Count > DestSh.Rows.Count Then
                MsgBox "There are not enough rows in the Destsh"
                GoTo ExitTheSub
            End If

            'This example copies values/formats, if you only want to copy the
            'values or want to copy everything look at the example below this macro
            CopyRng.Copy
            With DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "A")
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
            End With

            'Optional: This will copy the sheet name in the H column
            DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "H").Resize(CopyRng.Rows.Count).Value = sh.Name

        End If
    Next

ExitTheSub:

    Application.Goto DestSh.Cells(1)

    'AutoFit the column width in the DestSh sheet
    DestSh.Columns.AutoFit

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Also . . .

```
'Common Functions required for all routines

Function LastRow(sh As Worksheet)
    On Error Resume Next
    LastRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Row
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function


Function LastCol(sh As Worksheet)
    On Error Resume Next
    LastCol = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Column
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```