# Search for a string and move files containing string from source folder to destination folder

Tags: excel, vba

I have large number of .csv files in a folder and each file has few separation codes in them. Separation code usually will be 5 digit code eg: B82A6.

I have to copy files with a certain separation code and move them to a destination folder.

I am new to VBA. I've been searching for code to modify it to my use.

```
Sub Test()
Dim R As Range, r1 As Range
Dim SourcePath As String, DestPath As String, SeperationCode As String

SourcePath = "C:\Users\hr315e\Downloads\Nov_03_2019\"
DestPath = "C:\Users\hr315e\Downloads\Target\"
Set r1 = Range("A1", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

For Each R In r1
    SeperationCode = Dir(SourcePath & R)

    Do While SeperationCode <> ""

        If Application.CountIf(r1, SeperationCode) Then
            FileCopy SourcePath & SeperationCode, DestPath & SeperationCode

            R.Offset(0, 1).Value = SeperationCode

        Else

            MsgBox "Bad file: " & SeperationCode & " ==>" & SeperationCode & "<== "

        End If

       SeperationCode = Dir(SourcePath & "B82A6" & R.Value & "B82A6")
    Loop
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: A question - this separation codes are inside of the .csv file or in it's name? Anyway, you need to loop through files in folders and depending on where the code is  - open file and look for it, or evaluate its name. You may look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58801191/vba-code-to-copy-specific-range-cells-from-multiple-sheets-to-one-sheet/58802736#58802736) how to loop through files in folder.

Comment: Yes, this separation codes are inside of the .csv files and not in it's name. I have looked into the code that you linked and it is a little different than what I need because I am looking for Files that contain this string and not the string itself. I need to copy all the files that has this separation code in them and then have to paste them in a destination.

Comment: So, you may adapt the code from link, but instead of just copying - open it first, check whether it is the one you need, close it and copy if it fits the condition. Excel knows how to open .csv files.

Comment: And also, add comment to each line of your code which describes what it, you think, does.

Answer (score 0):

So, here's the code that should work for you.
As you can see, this is a version of code which I linked to you with small updates:

```
Sub GoThroughFilesAndCopy()

Dim BrowseFolder As String, DestinationFolder As String
Dim FileItem As Object
Dim oFolder As Object
Dim FSO As Object
Dim TempFileName As String
Dim CheckCode As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ' selecting the folder with files
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Title = "Select the folder with files"
        .Show
        On Error Resume Next
        Err.Clear
        BrowseFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            MsgBox "You didn't select anything!"
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            Exit Sub
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
    ' or you may hardcode it (data from your post):
    'BrowseFolder = "C:\Users\hr315e\Downloads\Nov_03_2019\"


    ' selecting the destination folder
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Title = "Select the the destination folder"
        .Show
        On Error Resume Next
        Err.Clear
        DestinationFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            MsgBox "You didn't select anything!"
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            Exit Sub
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
    ' or you may hardcode it (data from your post):
    'DestinationFolder = "C:\Users\hr315e\Downloads\Target\"


    CheckCode = "Some string" ' this is you check code


    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") ' creating filesystem object
    Set oFolder = FSO.getfolder(BrowseFolder) ' creating folder object

    For Each FileItem In oFolder.Files 'looking through each file in selected forlder
        TempFileName = ""
        If UCase(FileItem.Name) Like "*.CSV*" Then 'try opening only .csv files
            TempFileName = BrowseFolder & Application.PathSeparator & FileItem.Name ' getting the full name of the file (with full path)
            If CheckTheFile(TempFileName, CheckCode) Then ' if the file passes the checking function
                If Dir(DestinationFolder & Application.PathSeparator & FileItem.Name) = "" Then 'if the file doesn't exist in destination folder
                    FileCopy Source:=TempFileName, Destination:=DestinationFolder & Application.PathSeparator & FileItem.Name  ' it is copied to destination
                Else ' otherwise, there are to options how to deal with it further

                    'uncomment the part you need below:

                    ' this will Overwrite existing file
                    'FSO.CopyFile Source:=TempFileName, Destination:=DestinationFolder & Application.PathSeparator & FileItem.Name

                    ' this will get new name for file and save it as copy
                    'FileCopy Source:=TempFileName, Destination:=GetNewDestinationName(FileItem.Name, DestinationFolder)

                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

'////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Function CheckTheFile(File As String, Check As String) As Boolean
Dim TestLine As String
Dim TestCondition As String

TestCondition = "*" & Check & "*" ' this is needed to look for specific text in the file, refer to Like operator fro details

CheckTheFile = False

Open File For Input As #1 ' open file to read it line by line
    Do While Not EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, TestLine ' put each line of the text to variable to be able to check it

        If TestLine Like TestCondition Then ' if the line meets the condition
            CheckTheFile = True             ' then function gets True value, no need to check other lines as main condition is met
            Close #1                        ' don't forget to close the file, beacuse it will be still opened in background
            Exit Function                   ' exit the loop and function
        End If
    Loop
Close #1 ' if condiotion is not found in file just close the file, beacuse it will be still opened in background

End Function

'////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Function GetNewDestinationName(File As String, Destination As String) As String
Dim i As Integer: i = 1

Do Until Dir(Destination & Application.PathSeparator & "Copy (" & i & ") " & File) = "" ' if Dir(FilePath) returns "" (empty string) it means that the file does not exists, so can save new file with this name
    i = i + 1   ' incrementing counter untill get a unique name
Loop

GetNewDestinationName = Destination & Application.PathSeparator & "Copy (" & i & ") " & File ' return new file name

End Function
```

Basically, there is one sub, which is mostly copy-paste from linked topic, and two simple functions.